# посчитать календарь нужного года без модулей

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar

Помогите исправить код или направьте на путь истинный

```
skoka_dney=[0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
nedeli=[0,7,3,3,6,1,4,6,2,5,7,3,5]
sdn = ["Пн","Вт","Ср","Чт","Пт","Cб","Вc"]
mesyaci = ["","Январь","Февраль","Март","Aпpeль","Maй","Июнь","Июль","Aвгуст","Cентябрь","Oктябрь","Ноябрь","Дeкaбрь"]
g = '\t'
while True:
    vvod=int(input('Календарь какого года вам требуется, хозяин? >>>'))
    spec=vvod-2017
    s1=[];s2=[];s3=[];s4=[];s5=[];s6=[];s7=[];s8=[];s9=[];s10=[];s11=[];s12=[]
    s=[0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12]
    for i in range(1,13):
        for j in range(1,skoka_dney[i]+1):
            if nedeli[i]+(spec%7) > 7:
                w = spec%7
            else:
                w = nedeli[i]+(spec%7)
            s[i].append(int(j))
            s[i].append(int(w))
            if w < 7:
                w += 1
            else:
                w = 1
        print()
        print(mesyaci[i])
        for y in sdn:
            print(y, '\t',end='')
        print()
        if nedeli[i]+(spec%7) > 7:
            a = spec%7
        else:
            a = nedeli[i]+(spec%7)
        ch = a 
        a -= 1
        print(g*a, end='')
        for v in range(1,skoka_dney[i]+1):
            print(v, '\t', end='')
            if ch%7 == 0:
                print()
                ch += 1
            else:
                ch += 1
    print()
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы программа высчитывала календарь нужного года **без модулей**, я пытался, но получилось только если год позже 2017 и не високосный.

Comment: Вот: https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C#Python

Comment: @MaxU _Спасибо_ **большое**

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую вам прочесть [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), потому как ваш код читать затруднительно.